Prevent programs from writing to a partition
I have a hard drive in one partition with important data on it.
I want to prevent programs from writing to it.
It would be nice, for example, if I could grant access to certain programs like a whitelist? (not necessary)
The idea seems simple, but I searched the Internet and did not find an idea.
Sorry, but I'm new to superuser.

Encrypt just that partition, e.g., with VertaCrypt. Nothing can write (or read) it until it's unlocked.

Yeah, unfortunately the security model you are envisioning does not work well with the way software is designed.  Most disk writing is done through OS calls, so so its abstracted away from the end programs making it difficult.   I'd reconsider the way you are trying to implement security - but consider judicial use of VM's and bitlocker and also different users for different programs.

You successfully denied access for all helping people here on which platform (Windows, Linux, etc) you are working and which operating system you are using.

Dr. Moishe, Veracrypt, not "VertaCrypt"!
Anyway, that software is like a vault, but not a multi-user vault with compartments for everyone. Veracrypt does not extend the ability to build segregated folder structures.

Option 1:  READ ONLY.. PERIOD
You will need to mount any of these partitions as READ ONLY just as you suggested.
The default is READ/WRITE as you already know.
This link will tell you how to do it but I will also give you the gist of it here.
We will pretend that windows mounted this partiton as D:\ for the sake of demonstration.
First, you will unmount the existing drive
If you want, you can pay attention to the Volume-GUID here so you will know what it is later.. you can guess it too.
mountvol ENTER will show you a list at the bottom with your D:\ on it.  You might cut-paste the info from the console to possibly simplify it later.
Something like:

\\?\Volume{ac0a84a0-3b42-11ee-97a7-bc091bdc34f2}\
    D:\


Then, we unmount the D: partition
mountvol D: /p (old versions of this command won't work, use diskman).
And use diskpart to remount it as read-only.
diskpart
list volume
select volume X (where X is the number that points at what was D:)
att vol set readonly
to check your work, detail vol

reassign when needed, using the volume ID printed by mountvol:
mountvol D: \\?\Volume{ac0a84a0-3b42-11ee-97a7-bc091bdc34f2}\
You can also mount the volume on an empty folder (Unix style) using the same tools:
mkdir C:\fs\backup-disk
mountvol C:\fs\backup-disk \\?\Volume{ac0a84a0-3b42-11ee-97a7-bc091bdc34f2}
Option 2:  "whitelist"ish..
Rather than preventing programs from writing to it, you can

back it up of course.. you said it was IMPORTANT!
prevent specific USERS from writing to it (even if it's everyone but "administrator").

Programs run as users, in this case, most of them as YOUR user.
Using the standard NTFS security settings, you can make it where your user has read only access to that entire partition overriding whatever permissions that might come from you also being an admin on your own box.
The easiest (and best here IMHO) is to make your own user a NON-ADMINISTRATOR and elevate only things you trust.
There are many many ways to skin this cat but these are two of the most common.

Those button markup codes are '' and ''.

Now THAT'S music to my ears @music2myear ! Thank you.

lol. I learned by finding a post that had these and clicking the Edit button.
